# TypeError: this.$store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm following a Vue 2 tutorial but got stuck by this error. I've checked multiple questions before posting this one because I'm still unsure of what did I do wrong. Any input will be appreciated!

App.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
    <!-- <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/> -->
    <TodoApp />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TodoApp from './components/TodoApp.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    // HelloWorld,
    TodoApp
}
}
</script>
  body {
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: #e8f7f0;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Store (index.js) code:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import TodoModule from './modules/TodoModule.js';

// Load vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        TodoModule
    }
});
```

Main.js code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

TodoApp.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Vuex Todo App</h3>
    <div class="todos">
      <div class="todo" v-for="todo in allTodos" :key="todo.id">
        {{ todo.title }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "TodoApp",
  computed: mapGetters(['allTodos'])
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

TodoModule.js code:

```
// import axios from "axios";

const state = {
    todos: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "first todo"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        title: "second todo"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "third todo"
    }
]
};

const getters = {
    allTodos: state => state.todos
};

const actions = {};

const mutations = {};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

No Error on Compiler:

[image: No Error on Compiler]

Error on Browser Console:

[image: Error on Browser Console]

=== UPDATE ===

I still haven't fix this issue and I have tried restarting the localhost server, even my own laptop to check if it'll fix it.. no luck there.
From what I've read from answers, is it possible that this error happen because of my vue installation? Or perhaps I forgot to install something else when starting the development?

=== UPDATE 2 ===
Found the culprit, apparently my vue and vuex npm package either got corrupted or has a conflict, changing the version of vue to 2.7.8 and vuex to 3.0.1 then rerun npm i (after deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json) has fixed the issue!
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok.

I could reproduce with no erros using TodoModule below.

```js
const TodoModule = {
  state: {
    todos: [{ title: "1" }, { title: "2" }, { title: "3" }, { title: "4" }]
  },

  getters: {
    allTodos: (state) => state.todos
  }
};

export default TodoModule;
```

If error continues, you could check the naming on your files.
The store `index.js` as you said should be named as `store.js`.

Or perhaps restart server.

Comment: thanks for the input, I've changed my code accordingly and restarted my laptop.. still no luck :(

Comment: Sorry to hear. I saw your edit. The stack error is pointing to vuex and store. At my end I was using versions of vue 2.7.8 and vuex 3.0.1, and it worked. You can try to change package versions to maybe find out

Comment: I was using vue 2.6.14 and vuex 4.0.2, after I follow your version IT WORKED! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem while using Vue 2.

`npm uninstall vuex`

then

`npm i vuex@3.0.1`

`npm install vuex` by default npm installs version 4 which is not supported by Vue 2

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/releases

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have actually done the same youtube tutorial on vuex state management but I didn't use the mapGetter helper function, instead, I used the vanilla functions of vuex for getting and setting global variables.

main.js

```
store: new vuex.Store({
state: {
  user: {}
},
mutations: {
  setUser(state, payload){
    state.user = payload;
  }
},
getters: {
  getUser: state => state.user,
}})
```

any-component.js

```
this.user = this.$store.getters.getUser; //get
this.$store.commit("setUser", this.user); //set
```

Comment: thanks for the input, unfortunately after refactoring my code to follow yours, it still give me an error.. I'm very very new over vue's store and state management so  it's also possible that I wrongly refactor your code :(
Although, I hope to try and use the mapGetter helper to learn more about it, seems more simpler?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change getter inTo

```js
export default {
  name: "TodoApp",
  computed: mapGetters(['allTodos'])
};
```

===>

```js
export default {
  name: "TodoApp",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allTodos'])
    }
};
```

Comment: I've actually tried this before and unfortunately it still give me this error..

Comment: Did you synchronize the version of vue & vuex?

Comment: Yep, I've put it in this post's update, it fixed the problem!